# Clone element of array with typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, clone

I am having the `car` object in this screenshot(I couldn't find a way to pretty print it here)

[image]

I would like to do a function that clones one of the two elements in the `factory`.

I tried it like this:

```
public cloneFactory(modelIndex: number, factoryIndex: number): void {
    const newFactory = this.car.model[modelIndex].factory.slice(factoryIndex, factoryIndex + 1);
    this.car.model[modelIndex].factory.push(newFactory[0]);
}
```

I also tried it the classic way:

```
public cloneFactory(modelIndex: number, factoryIndex: number): void {
    const newFactory = this.car.model[modelIndex].factory[factoryIndex];
    this.car.model[modelIndex].factory.push(newFactory);
}
```

The issue I am having is that if I, afterwards, change one of the values in the cloned object it also changes it in the original object. I cannot understand why and how / why are the original and the clone related after one of the methods above are executed.

What is the proper way of cloning an element of the array so that it can be, later, edited without the original object to be affected as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually cloning the object. You are pushing the reference to the same object again. To clone it you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const newFactory = Object.assign({}, this.car.model[modelIndex].factory[factoryIndex]);
```

Here's an example of how `Object.assign` works compared to just assigning a reference:

```
var obj = { a: 1 };
var objref2 = obj; // Just assigning reference; not a clone
var clone = Object.assign({}, obj); // Actual cloned copy of `obj`
obj.a = 100;
console.log(obj.a)
-> 100 // Value changed
console.log(objref2.a)
-> 100 // Value changed
console.log(clone.a)
-> 1 // Value unchanged
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much!